# Access Masterpage control on a basepage using FindControl

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, findcontrol, contentplaceholder

I have an ASP.NET website application on .NET 4.0. There is one Masterpage that contains the header and footer for all the aspx pages. The content comes from the individual aspx pages. I have BasePage.cs which all the aspx pages inherit from.

Now to the problem:
I have a HTML Select control on the masterpage, whose value I am trying to retrieve in the BasePage.cs using the below code

```
string language = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect)Master.FindControl("cmbLanguage")).Value;
```

I am using this inside the InitializeCulture method, which would set the Culture info for the website.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{

    string language = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect)Master.FindControl("cmbLanguage")).Value;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
        CultureInfo(language);
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

While debugging, I can see that the expected value is set in the `language` variable. The problem is when the page renders, the content inside the ContentPlaceHolder for the aspx page is not being rendered.

I can see that it is the code involving `FindControl` which is the cause, because if I set the language to a string, everything works as expected.

```
string language = "de-DE";
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
If there is some content on the ContentPlaceHolder on the MasterPage, then it gets rendered instead of the page ContentPlaceHolder.

Comment: Is any content(Markup) in  **ContentPlaceHolder** of MasterPage?  Markup in contentplaceholder control wont be rendered.

Comment: @AVD: There is no content in the ContentPlaceHolder of the MasterPage.

Comment: forget about the master page, you can't access any control at the moment of InitializeCulture call, because they simply don't exist. You need to follow the solutions suggested in the answers: cookies, query string values + session or only query string values, url rewriting (www.mysite.com/en/products)

Answer (score 2):

InitializeCulture is called before even PreInit in the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), which means the controls haven't been setup, and the Value of that control is likely coming through as an empty string.

You need to likely change how the culture is read, through a cookie, session value, or some other method. I'm not familiar with doing it, so i don't have a great suggestion or best practice.

Comment: I can see while debugging, that the value is indeed being picked up right as "de-DE". Even if it is returning an empty string, why would the Content in the page contentplaceholder not show up? I tried, setting the language to empty string, and the content of the contentplaceholder renders correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As Doozer correctly noted that control is unlikely to have the correct value set up into it at the time of `InitializeCulture`. I will suggest that you read the value from POST data in the request and back it via some default value. For example,

```
string language = Request.Form[Master.FindControl("cmbLanguage")).UniqueID];
language = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language) ? "de-DE" : language;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access MasterPage controls its better to use [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) directive. When used you are going to be able to access master page in a strongly typed way. In this case you will be able to create a property on master page like this:

```
public string SelectedCulture
{
    get
    {
        return cmbLanguage.Value
    }
}
```

And on page itself you will be able to run code like this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() {
    string language = this.Master.SelectedCulture;

}
```